# How many threads are placed in a process

Tags: c, process, pthreads

How can I see the number of threads placed in a process in C ?

Actually, What I find out is whether newly-created process has one thread or no thread.(I am working in Linux)

Comment: Every process has at least one thread (the "main" thread)

Comment: In this case, we can say that when we create a thread in a process by using pthread_create() method, two threads exist in that process ?

Comment: at least two threads

Comment: @Goktug In C threading isn't very evolved. I believe the call you are looking for is `pthread_join()` which will block waiting for the thread to terminate. Any other status updates requires you to roll your own shared data structure. Yes, in theory `pthread_create()` will add a thread (although I've seen it butchered and abused many times).

Answer (score 1):

The `pthread_create()` function starts a new thread in the calling process.So technically yes you can say there are two threads.The main thread,however remains the dominating one ,returning from `main()` causes the termination of all threads in the process.

Comment: A detached thread can outlive the main function terminating. This isn't the default but calling `pthread_detach()` would make it so.